# Symfony2 locale type form element with limited list

Tags: symfony, locale

I want to add in my `MyType` form `locale` field, so I put:

```
$builder->add('locale', 'locale', array(
  'label'       => 'user.locale',
  'required'    => true,
));
```

However it rendered me a whole list of available locales because default `choices` array for this type is:

```
'choices' => Intl::getLocaleBundle()->getLocaleNames()
```

I would like to display only `en`, `de` and `pl`. How can I limit the output to those languages ?

The best solution would be with defining this list in `config.yml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```php
$builder->add('locale', 'locale', array(
    'label'     => 'user.locale',
    'required'  => true,
    'choices'   => array('en' => 'English', 'de' => 'Deutsch', 'pl' => 'Polish')
));
```

See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html) for getting these values from configuration.

Edit : Thanks to Djuro Mandinic for pointing the error in my previous answer, the `choices` array must contain keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

"The choices option defaults to all locales." 
on http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/forms/types/locale.html

Specify your choices explicitly, eg. `'choices'=>array('en'=>'en','de'=>'de','pl'=>'pl')`